# Registering a custom TableCell xib gives me an error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I get the error:

> Argument labels '(_:, forCellWithReuseIdentifier:)' do not match any
>   available overloads

I'm not sure why, since this works perfectly for my CollectionView Cells:

```
class DashboardVC: UIViewController,  UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

let ownedItemArray = ["Owned Item 1","Owned Item 2","Owned Item 3"]
let shopItemArray = ["Shop Item 1","Shop Item 2","Shop Item 3", "Shop Item 4","Shop Item 5","Shop Item 6"]
let freeItemArray = ["Free Item 1","Free Item 2","Free Item 3"]


@IBOutlet weak var ownedItemsCollection: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var shopItemsCollection: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var freeItemsTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ownedItemsCollection.delegate = self
    ownedItemsCollection.dataSource = self
    shopItemsCollection.delegate = self
    shopItemsCollection.dataSource = self
    freeItemsTableView.delegate = self
    freeItemsTableView.dataSource = self

    ownedItemsCollection.register(UINib(nibName:"OwnedCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "owned_item")
    shopItemsCollection.register(UINib(nibName: "ShopListCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "shoplist_item")
    freeItemsTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "FreeItem", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "free_items")

}
```

Comment: YourCollectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CustomOneCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCellOne") see this

Comment: Cell must be UIcollectionviewCell class

Comment: class CustomOneCell: UICollectionViewCell {
}

Comment: Your code is correct. Did you try clean and build again?

Comment: @iOSDeveloper, yes I have restarted and tried to rebuild the full error when I build is: "Overloads for 'register' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (UINib?, forCellReuseIdentifier: String), (AnyClass?, forCellReuseIdentifier: String), (UINib?, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: String), (AnyClass?, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: String)" Maybe there is a conflict because I already have CollectionViews?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya yes by Cells are CollectionView Cells for the first two and they dont have an issue, it is only the TableView that has the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `UITableView` use
`freeItemsTableView.register(UINib(nibName: cellNibName, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseId)`.
Pay attention to second parameter name, it's not `forCellWithReuseIdentifier` but `forCellReuseIdentifier`.

Comment: nice observation. Brewski, please use code completion :)